# Combinatorics with n case

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Show that if n is a positive integer, then 
$${2n\choose0} + {2n\choose2}+ \dots + {2n\choose2n} = 2^{2n-1}$$
I assume the proof is done by induction but how to I do the k+1 case?

Comment: Are you talking about the Lagrange-symbol? Just to be sure. Or are they binomials formatted as fractions?

Comment: How is dividing by zero possible? See the first term (2n/0).

Comment: What do you mean with 'the $k+1$ case'?

Comment: It is a combinatorics questions that is the notation for combinations.

Comment: K+1 case is for induction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you want to take an even number of books out of $2n$ books with you on your holiday. The left hand side sums the number of possibilities over all possible amounts $2k$ to take with you. On the right hand side, for the first $2n-1$ books, you decide whether or not you take it with you. Then the last book is chosen only if you selected an odd number of books within the first $2n-1$ books. Now we have counted the same number of possibilities in two ways, resulting in
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}=2^{2n-1}$$

Comment: Ok am I suppose you use this to prove the equality for the n+1 case?

Comment: No, I don't use induction to prove the equality. this is just a direct proof that is valid for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: I dont see how you can do this as a direct proof can you please explain the process?

Comment: My explanation is valid for any $n$, and because we count the same number of possibilities in two ways, the expressions that belong to the two countings have to be equal.

Comment: I am just having a hard time translating this into a proof

Comment: Do you understand all steps I make?
This IS the proof, but you may not be used to such a proof.

Comment: I think that is it.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Pascal's identity and then the binomial theorem. Alternatively, look at the expansion of $\frac{(1+x)^{2n} + (1-x)^{2n}}{2}$ and then plug in $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The left side counts the number of subsets of a set with 2n elements that have an even number of elements, and there is a bijection between the subsets with an even number of elements and the subsets with an odd number of elements.
(See [Exactly half of the elements of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ are odd-sized](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248245/exactly-half-of-the-elements-of-mathcalpa-are-odd-sized))

Since a set with 2n elements has $2^{2n}$ subsets, the left side must equal $2^{2n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the Binomial theorem for:

$$(1+1)^{2n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the sum of a row of Pascal's Triangle behaves this way:

$\dbinom{2n}{0}+\dbinom{2n}{1}+\dbinom{2n}{2}+\cdots+\dbinom{2n}{2n}=2^{2n}$

Also that:

$\dbinom{2n}{0}-\dbinom{2n}{1}+\dbinom{2n}{2}-\dbinom{2n}{3}+\cdots+(-1)^{2n}\dbinom{2n}{2n}=0$

Therefore:

$\dbinom{2n}{0}+\dbinom{2n}{2}+\cdots+\dbinom{2n}{2n}= \dbinom{2n}{1}+\dbinom{2n}{3}+\cdots+\dbinom{2n}{2n-1}$

And now you can conclude that:

$2[\dbinom{2n}{0}+\dbinom{2n}{2}+\cdots+\dbinom{2n}{2n}]= 2^{2n}$

Finally, as stated:

$\dbinom{2n}{0}+\dbinom{2n}{2}+\cdots+\dbinom{2n}{2n}=2^{2n-1}$