# Odd Town Problem.

Tags: graph-theory

**QUESTION:**
A town with $n$ inhabitants has $m$ clubs such that each club has an odd number of members and any two different clubs have an even number of common members.
     Show that $m\leq n$.

**ATTEMPT:**
We argue by contradiction.
    Let $M$ be the smallest value of $m$ for which the proposition is false.

So we assume that there is a town with $N$ inhabitants and $M$ clubs satisfying the conditions of the problem but still having $M>N$.

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph having $X$ and $Y$ as its partite sets.
    The members of $X$ are the clubs and the members of $Y$ are the inhabitants.
    We join a vertex $A\in X$ with a vertex $p\in Y$ iff $p$ is in the club $A$.

Now if there exists $S\subsetneq X$ such that $|N(S)|<|S| $ then consider another town which has $N(S)$ as its inhabitants and $S$ as its clubs.
    Then we see that this town defies the proposition but with a smaller number of clubs than $M$, contradicting the minimality of $M$.
    Thus we may assume that $|N(S)|\geq |S|$ for all $S\subsetneq X$.

Let $S\subseteq X$ with $|S|=M-1$.
    Now by Hall's Theorem, there is a matching in $G$ saturating $S$ into $Y$, giving $|Y|\geq M-1$.

So the only possibility we need to rule out is $M=N+1$ and here I am stuck.

I have not been able to make use of the facts that the degree of each vertex in $X$ is odd and that $|N(x_1)\cap N(x_2)|$ is even whenever $x_1,x_2\in X$ with $x_1\neq x_2$.

Can somebody please help me from here?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling this was asked before some time ago. [Yes! Here it is.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739330/proving-a-bound-for-oddtown-eventown-or-clubtown)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think it is the same problem. The conditions on the clubs are different. Can you please check again? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right (which is why I didn't vote to close the question). I'm gonna leave my comment so the next person which has a deja vu doesn't vote to close.

Comment: Check here for a proof with linear algebra http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=The_Oddtown_theorem

Comment: @Jernej Cool proof. Thanks. But I think I am really looking for a graph theoretic solution.