# Binomal theorem show that $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+\dots=\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{5}+\dots=2^{n-1}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm having some trouble with this question

> Show that
>   $$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+\dots=\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{5}+\dots=2^{n-1}$$

Attempt:

Expanding $(1+1)^n=2^n$
$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{4}+\dots+\binom{n}{n}=2^n$$

Expanding $(1-1)^n=0$
$$\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{4}+\dots+(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}=0$$

And I'm stuck here. The solution says "Adding these two equalities yields the required one".

I can see how the terms will cancel out,however I don't see how $2^n+0 = 2^{n-1}$

Comment: left side the even coeffiecients addup producing a factor of $2$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927716/show-that-n-choose-1-n-choose-3-cdots-n-choose-0-n-choose-2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add both equalities you got:

$$2\left(\binom n0+\binom n2+\ldots\right)=2^n+0$$

and now divide by two. Finally, oberve the symmetry between binomial coefficients $\;\binom nk\;$ with even $\;k\;$ and with odd $\;k\;$

Answer (score 1):

Also you can subtract equation 2) from 1) to get second part.