# $\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq 0}^{} \binom{n}{2k} = \sum_{k \geq 0}^{} \binom{n}{2k+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I read in twitter that: $$\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq 0}^{} \binom{n}{2k} = \sum_{k \geq 0}^{} \binom{n}{2k+1}$$
So far I've noticed that if $n$ is odd then $n=2k+1$ and we have that $$\binom{2k+1}{k-i} = \binom{2k+1}{k+1+i} $$ for $i= 0,1,\dots,k$

Since we must have that one of $k-i$ , $k+1+i$ must be odd and the other even for all $i=0,1,\dots,k$ then we must have that $$\displaystyle\sum_{l\geq 0}^{} \binom{2k+1}{2l} = \sum_{l \geq 0}^{} \binom{2k+1}{2l+1}$$
I don't know what to do when $n$ is even or if there's a way to prove this without breaking it into cases.

Comment: **Hint:** What is the binomial expansion of $(x+y)^n$?  What is the binomial expansion of $(1+(-1))^n$?

Comment: Depending on your preferred style/flavor of proof and what makes the most sense to you, you would do well to go to the linked question and look at the questions that are linked to/from that page to see dozens of other times this question has come up and the many solutions here, such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927716/show-that-n-choose-1-n-choose-3-cdots-n-choose-0-n-choose-2?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611761/alternating-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-given-n-in-mathbb-n-prove-sumn) and others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggestion: Look at $(1-1)^n$.