# colorings with exactly $k$ color changes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $n$ **distinct/distinguishable** beads arranged in a circle. Let's color each bead either black or white with probability $1/2$ independently. What is the probability that there are exactly $k$ pairs of neighboring beads whose colors are different?

For example, the bead circle $BWWB$ has two such pairs while the circle $BWWBW$ has four such pairs.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The probability you're looking for is independent of our ability to distinguish the beads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Since the probability model is uniform over all possible colorings, it suffices to count the number of colorings satisfying your condition, and then divide by $2^n$.

**Hint 2:** Note that $k$ must be even for the condition to make sense. [If you go around the circle, you switch colors $k$ times and then end up at the color you began with.] <s>This ended up being irrelevant.</s>

We now assume $k$ is even.

**Hint 3:**
To construct a coloring satisfying your condition, one can first mark where the $k$ "color changes" occur. After setting this, there are two possible ways to fill in the colors.

There are $n$ "gaps" between neighboring beads, so there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose where these color changes are. The probability is thus $$\frac{2 \binom{n}{k}}{2^n} = 2^{-n+1} \binom{n}{k}.$$ As a sanity check note that [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248245/exactly-half-of-the-elements-of-mathcalpa-are-odd-sized) implies $$2^{-n+1}\sum_{\substack{0 \le k \le n\\\text{$k$ even}}}\binom{n}{k} = 2^{-n+1} \frac{2^n}{2} = 1.$$

Thanks to lulu for catching my mistakes.

Comment: The method seems sensible, but is the answer correct?  If $n=2$, say, you either have no changes or two, so non-zero probabilities only for $k=0,2$ and probability $\frac 12$ for either.  But you give a non-zero probability for $k=1$, no? Also...do your values sum to $1$?

Comment: On further review...sticking to the $n=2$ case, you have two "gaps" but filling them is not an independent choice.  If you fill one, you automatically fill the other.  I think your crossed out parity observation has meaning.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for catching my embarrassing mistakes; will try to fix!

Comment: No problem.  I think all you have to do is to un-cross out your comment, and note that your formula only applies to the case of even $k$.

Comment: Edited version looks good (+1).