# Proof $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{2k} = 2^{2n-1}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Can someone help me prove the equation:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{2k} = 2^{2n-1}$$

I know that via binomial theorem for even k:
$$2^{2n} = (1+1)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k}$$
and for odd k: $$0 = (1-1)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k}\cdot(-1)^k$$
That's how i solve the equation:
$$2^{2n-1}=\frac{2^{2n}}{2}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k}}{2}$$ Now we can remove all odd k because they are equal 0.
Also only even k remain:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{2k}=2^{n+1}$$
And.. I have a mistake somewhere, because it must be: $$2^{n-1}$$
I think I don't fully understand the difference between odd k and the number of subsets with odd cardinality. Or odd k is an abbreviation for the number of subsets with odd cardinality?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248245/exactly-half-of-the-elements-of-mathcalpa-are-odd-sized) duplicate.

Comment: Note that $1+(-1)^k = 2$ when $k$ is even, this accounts for the missing $2$.

Comment: Consider a set with $2n$ elements. Make one its element special. Then all the combinations of elements of the set that include the special element are corresponding to the combinations without it (by adding/removing it).

Answer (score 1):

I think you had a confusion when you took the case of k odd and k even, in both sums there are k even and odd I did not understand your remark however here is my attempt:

\begin{align*}
0 &= (1-1)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} (-1)^k \\
\text{So:} \\
0 &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n}{2k+1} \\
\text{And:} \\
2^{2n} &= (1+1)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \\
\text{Then:} \\
2^{2n} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n}{2k+1} \\
\text{Therefore:} \\
2^{2n} &= 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} \\
\text{Finally:} \\
2^{2n-1} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k}
\end{align*}

Comment: There is a strong opinion (or rather, the enforced site policy) that it is better not to answer to a question which is a clear duplicate. You can always leave a comment to a question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Aig What do you mean by "clear duplicate"?

Comment: @NourBelghazi Please check the comments to the question. This question was posted a lot of times on the site!

Comment: @NourBelghazi Thank you! That’s has helped a lot.

Comment: I’m sorry for the duplicate but I was simply confused although I red the other similar questions asked before mine. What should I change? I shared my thoughts about the solution that I came up with, which obviously was false and I still needed help. It’s not easy to find good mathematicians with knowledge of analysis, combinatorics etc. And I’m grateful for the commends and for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have $2n-1$ beans on the table and you want to pick some subset of them.
Borrow another bean and color it red. Now pick a subset of the remaining $2n$ beans of even cardinality, and throw out the red one if it's in there.