# Why the number of Nim winning positions is not equal to the number of losing positions?

Tags: combinatorics, logic, combinatorial-game-theory

maybe I miss something and I like to know where is my mistake:
Lets suppose we play [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) with $n$ piles, and lets say we we limit each pile to be between $0$ to $k$.
Now, according to this question: [How to prove that subset at odd size is equal to subset at even size?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218869/how-to-prove-that-subset-at-odd-size-is-equal-to-subset-at-even-size/4218874) the amount of the winning situations should be equal to the loosing situations, why?

Because we can translate the piles to binary numbers, like:
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}$$

And we are loosing iff the sum of each column is $0$.
In other words - we are loosing if each column have even times of $1$'s (like: 0,2,4,...).

Now, what I'm not understating is this:
The amount of even times of 1's is equals the the odd times of 1's, so why the we have more winning situation the loosing situations? (I run a program to check it and this was the result).

I assume it's because the AND, i.e. that **each** column must be with even amount of 1's.
But I'm stack here....

I'd like to understnad what I miss here.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it’s because of the AND.  Intuitively, there are more winning than losing positions in many impartial games because there only needs to be *one* good move to make a position winning; whereas *all* moves must be bad to make a position losing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there are five columns. There are $2^5=32$ ways to fill each column with ones and zeroes, while there are $2^{5-1}=16$ ways to fill each column with an even number of ones. It is true that $16$ is one half of $32$. However, the number of ways to make *all* of the columns have an even number of ones is $16^5$, while the total number of ways to fill the matrix is $32^5$. Note that $16^5$ is not equal to one half of $32^5$. Instead, the proportion of losing positions is $(1/2)^5$.

It helps to think of it probabilistically. If you fill out the first column randomly, the probability there is an even number of ones in the first column is $1/2$. If you fill all columns randomly, then the probability they all have an even number of ones is $(1/2)^5$, since the columns are all independent.

In general, if you have $n$ piles, where each pile size is less than $2^r$ for some $r\in \mathbb N$, then the proportion of losing positions $(1/2)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is my solution:*
Lets say that: $p$ is the number of the piles, and $n$ is the maximum size of each pile, and for make much easier lets assume that: $n=2^k-1$ (for $k\in \mathbb{N}_+$) and $q = \left\lceil \log_{2}\left(n\right)\right\rceil $.

For loosing positions:
Each column **must** have even 1's, and because we now that we have $2^p$ subsets overall and the amount of even 1's subsets is equal to the the amount of odd 1's subsets, the amount of even 1's is $2^{p-1}$ (and this is the the amount of the odd 1's).
We have $q$ columns and it should be at each column, so:
$$\overbrace{2^{p-1}\cdot2^{p-1}\cdots2^{p-1}}^{q} = (2^{p-1})^q$$

The winning positions is all the possible positions ($2^{pq})$ minus the loosing positions:
$$2^{pq}-(2^{p-1})^q$$

And if we will mark: $2^{p}=\varDelta$, we will get:
$$\varDelta^q-\left(\frac{\varDelta}{2}\right)^q$$

So as $n$ is bigger $q$ is bigger, hence the the difference between the loosing and winning positions is bigger.
For example: If $n=1$ the $q=0$ and then the winning postion = loosing positions,
but if $n=2$ - the amount of winning potsitons is bigger $3$ times then the amount of loosing positions.